# Ask Question Component issue when switching header Search Box

Tags: lightning-aura-components, napili, lightning-community

When switching a lightning community search from the Search & Post Publisher component to the Global Search Box Component, the Ask a Question component seems to "break". I am testing this in a dev org.

These are both OOTB SF lightning components.

Global Search Box Component

[image]

Ask A Question Component is in the lower right part of the screen (In Green)
[image]

Apparently, when clicking the Ask a question component, a post is supposed to be triggered:

```
    aura?r=16&Component.reportFailedAction=4&PublisherTopicsWidget.
showAddTopicsWidgetInPublisher=1
```

has anyone encountered this issue or might have further insight on this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue and taken as a Bug by Salesforce which will be fixed in upcoming releases.

The Known Issue can be found here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008pUOQAY

Fixed as of this winter release (2017)